# Attaching an event when creating "Link to a location on the same page"

Tags: html, javascript

In the fiddle posted here: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwinkumark/V8RXG/) clicking on 
'Check Chapter 4' takes me to another location on the same page.

When I press the back button on the browser it takes me back to the top of the page.

How to add an event (say, an alert dialogue) to the `<p>` tag in the example to be called when it is revisited or returned from another link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't attach an event of that kind to the P tag, but you can have an event that triggers when the anchor (the part after the #) changes.

In modern browsers there is an actual event for that. In older browsers you will need to constantly check if it changed.

If you are OK with jQuery then you can use http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Ariel, but different project. This one doesn't require jQuery.

http://code.google.com/p/dshistory/